# Preselect value and pass selected value in select box

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options

I have a dropdown with a list of users. The list is used to assign a user to a task. I can preselect the user that is assigned by setting the model to `task.assignedId` which is mapped to the user, and I can assign a new user if I set the model to `user` and pass that into an `ng-change` on the select. The problem I'm having is doing both of those things. How can I have a preselected value and then pass in the new value that is selected to my update method?

Here is the current code I have which is setting the current user correctly but not passing the new selected user:

```
<select ng-model="task.asigneeId" ng-change="assignUser(task)" 
       ng-options="user.id as user.firstName for user in users">
```

Comment: And you looked at ng-selected?http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSelected

Comment: I'm trying the ng-selected but I'm not having luck with it. I think my values are off so it doesn't select the correct user or something. My values for the options should be equal to the user id's but it doesn't seem like they are.

Comment: if you put your code in jsfiddle or plnkr, it will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

your `task` is a property already in scope, so you don't need to pass it to `assignUser` method.

```
ng-change="assignUser()"
```

Controller:

```
$scope.task = {
    asigneeId: 1,
    ....
};

$scope.assignUser = function() {
    // use $scope.task do something    

}
```

Comment: I think you have to pass it because that scope gets overwritten for each iteration of the loop. So task needs to be passed in to refer to the correct task of that scope.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it working correctly. To preselect the option, the model needs to be set to the property of the current tasks user id, which in this case is called task.assigneeId. That will map to the options value. Then to set the new value, all that is needed is passing the task into the update function and calling update. Because the user id is now already set through the model, it will update correctly. Here is the code:

HTML:

```
  ul class="task-list"
    li [ng-repeat='task in uncompletedTasks]
      p Assign-to:
        select ng-model="task.asigneeId" ng-change="assignUser(task)" ng-options="user.id as user.firstName for user in users"
        option value="" -- assign a user --
```

Angular Controller:

```
  $scope.assignUser = function(task) {
    task.update();
  }
```